# How to get specific value of an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I developed an image gallery using a jQuery plugin. Now I need to select an attribute value of a selected image. For this I used the following code.

```
var img=$('li.selected');
var comm = $("textarea#comm").val();
var dataid=$(img).attr('data-id');
var dataalid=$(img).attr('data-alid');
```

and in html page the selected list is:

```
<li class="selected" style="margin-right: 3px; width: 69px;">
```

That is following list:

```
<div class="es-carousel" id="loader">
<ul class="es-carousel">
<li><a href="#"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSwAEASSlPA47U..../9kA"  alt="xyz" data-description="Retrieving images with jquery and servlet" data-id="1" data-alid="6"/></a></li>
 ...
</div>
```

I need to get the value of `data-id` and `data-alid`. I don't know how to get the value. I'm newbie in jQuery.

Please anyone help me. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `.attr()`; use `.data()`.

Comment: Just as a point... you don't need to add the element selector in most cases. Especially for ID's. To make things a little more efficient you can change the selectors to `var img = $('.selected img');` and `$("#comm").val();`. Also, because the variable img is already a jQuery object you don't need to wrap it as a jQuery object, for example `img.attr('data-id');` should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When doing this:

```
var img=$('li.selected');
```

You are selecting the `LI` element, not the `IMG`. You should do it like this:

```
var img = $('li.selected img');
```

Furthermore, you don’t need to wrap the `img` in jQuery again, just do:

```
var dataid = img.attr('data-id');
```

Or even:

```
var dataid = img.data('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable on your first line is called img, so you probably mean to get the image inside in the list item, but your just getting the list item itself.

Try this instead:

```
 var img = $('li.selected img');
```